# Qual a melhor forma de ler um json em flutter?

Tags: json, flutter

Estou entrando no mundo do desenvolvimento e aprendendo Flutter para programar para mobiles.

O funcionamento básico do meu app vai ser ler um JSON do meu server e jogar em uma lista no app.

Dúvidas:

1. Quais são as boas práticas para fazer isso?
2. Crio uma classe e para cada item do meu json eu instancio?
3. Ou simplesmente pego a string resposta do json e jogo em um Map(que
   é tipo um dictionary no python), ou faço de algum outro jeito?

Comment: [Tratamento JSON no flutter da forma mais fácil (serialization)](https://magrizo.wordpress.com/2019/02/12/tratamento-json-no-flutter-da-forma-mais-facil-serialization/)

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui neste artigo que publiquei no Medium [Descomplicando o JSON em Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-comunidade-br/descomplicando-o-json-em-flutter-47e12b87753b)